# Find marginal distributions of $f(x,y) = 1$ within shaded area A, given by boundaries $y = x^2, ~y = x^2 + 1$ and $ 0 < x < 1.$

Tags: probability, self-study, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution, integral

I understand that I'm supposed to integrate with respect to x and y to find the marginal distribution of Y and X respectively, but my answers seem wrong. I got marginal distribution of $X = 1$ and of $Y = \sqrt{(y)} + 1 - \sqrt{(y-1)}. $

Comment: Hi. Since this is an assignment (homework) problem, you ought to add the [tag:self-study] tag which I have done this time.

Comment: Please do show your answer (even you thought it is wrong) as attempts to solve the problem.  By the way, the last sentence of your post hardly makes sense:  what do you mean by "*marginal distribution of $X = 1$*"?